# Sshfs, Textmate & Rails project, very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion, textmate, sshfs

I am a Linux user and I recently bought a MAC.
I work on a big project that needs to run on a dedicated server.

With Gedit and SSHFS, I had no problem to load the Rails project, same when I create a new controller/model from the command line, refreshing the files tree of Gedit is instantaneous, no slowdowns.

I installed Homebrew, then fuse4x and sshfs. I mount my server like on linux:

```
sshfs my.server.tld:/home/me Sshfs/my.server.tld/ -o 'volname=MyServer'
```

so far so good.

I open Textmate then I load my project ... disaster, two minutes+ to load the whole project
I'm switch another window... back to textmate... refresh again with the focus. But fixed with Remate after some research.

But now when creating new resources from command line, I need to refresh whole project for getting new files and it can take two minutes and more

Tried expandrive, same issue.

What the problem ? Textmate ? Sshfs on mac ?

I have googled long time, and most of people doesn't seem to have slowdowns with sshfs
I am a little depressed I had always dreamed to use TextMate !

EDIT:
So, this is definitely TextMate.

I have tried with Sublime Text 2 and it work *very very* good (better than gedit :p)
Save/open/project refresh are very fast

And even with an NFS share through a VPN it work good.

Answer (score 2):

Both.

TextMate can be very slow and beachball-happy when working over slow networks or networks with big latency. Some years ago, when Fuse was ported to Mac OS X, a plugin was created that inhibited a few features to make TextMate more responsive in such cases. [Here it is](http://ciaranwal.sh/remate/), I've never used it, though, so no guarantees.

I've never managed to enjoy using SSHFS on Mac OS X: slow save, slow copy, slow open… it was never worth the trouble, even on local network or using Expandrive.

Answer (score -2):

You should try to start textmate from a different directory, so that it writes temp files to local disk.