# Opening Rails project over SSHFS crashes TextMate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sshfs, textmate2

I'm trying to access a Rails project which is on a friend's server.

I have installed OSXFUSE, MacFUSE, and MacFusion, plus the standalone SSHFS package on my Mac OS 10.7.4 system.

I wanted to use MacFusion but after TextMate crashed, I decided to follow the instructions from Macromates (http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/Howtos#Macfuse):

```
sshfs user@servername:/ ~/mnt/servername -o'ping_diskarb,volname=servername'
cd ~/mnt/servername/projectfolder
mate .
```

TextMate launches but immediately becomes unresponsive until I force it to quit. Sublime Text 2 has no such issue.

Any advice on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution to this and found this seemed to work:

```
sshfs -o no_readahead,noappledouble,nolocalcaches user@server:. /mount/
```

From HERE: [Sshfs, Textmate & Rails project, very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951744/sshfs-textmate-rails-project-very-slow)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/macfusion-devel/D3A8tyTsApw

Comment: I'm actually not sure this helped.  I think my problem is an issue of TextMate opening large directories in general.  In the end I've opened a smaller directory and it seems to work.